# Suggested-Edits-Tool displays more approved users than in edit overview

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

The [Suggested-Edits-Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits) displays more users that approve an edit, than are listed in the overview of an edit.

For example the edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2300090 list the 4 users

> Approved 6 mins ago:
>
> - martineau reviewed this 5 mins ago: Approve
> - WATTO Studios reviewed this 5 mins ago: Approve
> - pXL reviewed this 9 mins ago: Reject
>     This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.
> - Royston Pinto reviewed this 11 mins ago: Approve

but in the Tools the following users are listed

> approved by Volatility, toro2k, danodonovan, Kaz Dragon, Royston
>   Pinto, WATTO Studios, martineau, pXL 7 mins ago

Also has user pXL `rejected` the edit and not approved.

I think the Tools list all users that reviewed the edit, but the edit overview lists only first users that reviewed the edit to complete the review state.

If its the case the Tools should say `reviewed by`.

Comment: I noticed the suggested edit tool for the first time :)