# Suggested Edits Dashboard doesn't agree with Suggested Edits view

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

I recall [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3223513):

[image]

It was one that I knew could use a bit more spit and polish, but I didn't have the inclination or energy to edit it myself, so I skipped it.

I wander my way over to [Suggested Edits Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits) (10K only), and look at the listing...

[image]

...so, when did I approve this again? I **skipped** the question; that doesn't mean I gave my tacit approval, does it?

Seems like the dashboard needs to agree with the suggested edits view.

Comment: Looks like it's displaying all users who took action on that item - no matter what type of action.

Comment: It [was reported before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184090/152859) but since this report is much better voting to close the older one as dupe of this.

Comment: Just stumbled across the same. Skipping a suggested edit is listed as approval in the list view. Probably a trivial error in the underlying SQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fix is rolling out with build rev `2014.12.1.2057` to sites, thanks to [this recent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244457/weird-edit-approvers-list) which brought the issue to my attention.

Comment: [One more dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184090/suggested-edits-tool-displays-more-approved-users-than-in-edit-overview) to mark as completed. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard meh, we don't care about dupes... I tagged the one I linked to in my answer with [tag:status-completed] before I closed it as a dupe of this one.

Comment: Well, others do mark dupes as well... but no big deal.

Answer (score 6):

The current format is:

> Approved/Rejected by [people who took any action including skip]

It isn't ideal, but once you understand all the people listed did not agree with the outcome, it's workable. It's not a huge issue either since this is pretty easy to understand despite the confusing wording.

**However**, it would be best if it said:

> **Approved/Rejected** by [people who reviewed according to outcome], Rejected/Approved by [people who reviewed against the outcome], skipped by [those who skipped]

(Bold to indicate it was the actual outcome)

But even this would be a quick & easy improvement:

> Approved/Rejected, reviewed by [people who took any action]

Skips are probably not something useful to know so it might be better to leave them out of there completely.

Comment: I think skip shouldn't be public. It's not visible anywhere.

Comment: @Sha except your own review history after 10k (for whatever reason)

Comment: I still think it's a bug, some kind of overlook on the dev's side.

Comment: @sha might be, and if so, removing it makes sense.