# Weird edit approvers list

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

I was going through [the list of controversial edits of the day](https://askubuntu.com/tools/suggested-edits?tab=controversial&filter=Day%5C) (possibly 10k link), when I came up on this:

> [image]

The [suggested edit link](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/348335) itself only lists KasiyA, Alvar and Eric Carvalho.

So what's going on here? An audit gone serious?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That page was displaying users that clicked `Skip`. It'll be fixed with the next build rev - `2014.12.1.2057`.

Comment: I have never seen a list that long before. Was this a bug recently introduced, or did I simply not see it in action before?

Comment: Got the answer. Thanks.