# Suggested Edits dashboard in 10 k tools list users who rejected an edit as approving it

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

In the 10 k tools, [this suggested edit](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7348) is described as if I had approved it:

[image: approved by […] Wrzlprmft]

However, the review item itself (correctly) displays that I rejected this edit:

[image: Wrzlprmft reviewed this […]: Reject]

Going by  [this question’s](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203154/255554) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), this should be fixed, but it isn’t.

This could be solved by replacing *approved by* to *reviewed by* in the list or making an explicit list, who approved and rejected an edit (which is probably more complicated).

Comment: I suppose that it is like a vote. It is 2-1 and the majority goes to `approved`. That's my guess

Comment: I agree with @PythonMaster. That is also how it works with the close notices on a question.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: No, it doesn’t. See, e.g. [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/review/close/8988): The user who voted to leave the question open is not listed on the close notice.