# Suggested edits stats show that a user who approved an edit rejected it

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, regression, suggested-edit-stats

In the [10k suggested edits stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits), there's a [suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/26991) that shows:

[image]

Except that the hat-collecting arachnid actually *approved* it:

[image]

This [was reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203154/suggested-edits-dashboard-doesnt-agree-with-suggested-edits-view) 7 and a bit years ago, and was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but it's not.

Comment: It might be a two-to-one majority thing, but it's still inaccurate.  It's also not the same for closed-question notices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suggested Edits dashboard in 10 k tools list users who rejected an edit as approving it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248542/suggested-edits-dashboard-in-10-k-tools-list-users-who-rejected-an-edit-as-appro) - that's basically the reverse situation but I bet the underlying problem is identical.